# Is there a possibility to add 2 buttons at the right corner of the NavigationBar in Ipad?

Tags: ipad, uinavigationbar

I'm developing one application in IPad.In that application i want to add 2 buttons at the right side corner.Before that i want to know if there is a possibility or not.If this is possible means please tell me how it is.

Comment: Please anyone help me out to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/06/uibuttons-in-uinavigationbar/

Comment: Thank You...The above link is more useful to achieve my requirement(for adding more then 2 button at the rightside corner)

Comment: You're welcome. Following the example in the link, you can create a custom button and add it the same way as the regular buttons.
For example: 
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 customButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,45,45);
 [customButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Alert_Small.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 
 UIBarButtonItem *customBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
 [buttons addObject:customBarButton];